# Chrome Extension - control on instance creations

Tags: google-chrome

I have installed few extension in Google Chrome browser. Those are very helpful to me while development.
But, as soon as i have started Chrome browser, each plug-in creates it's own instance in background and total memory allocation in RAM is more than 450 MB.

Is any way to set control on creation of instances on background.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Chrome Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Stability) forces each extension to run in a new process. In many cases, the extension's [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) is idle but because of being a new process consumes some basic memory that goes beyond the control of the developer of the app.

Unfortunately, there is no way to limit the creation of instances in background but you can disable the extensions that you are not currently use to reduce the memory allocation caused by them.

Hope it helps!